# Python Pandas to sort the highest number for json data

Tags: python, json, pandas

The url has data which is in json format. I would like to arrange the data for C in json. It is a long list data and I want to sort by the highest C value to the smallest. However, I just unable to read the json data in Pandas dataframe.

```
url ='http://www.bng.com/Jso/JsonstData?qryl'
pd.read_csv(url, index_col=[0,1])

>>>Empty DataFrameColumns: [items:[{ID:0, N:'2ndChance W200123', SIP:'', NC:'CDWW', R:'', I:'', M:'', LT:0.009, C:0.001, VL:0.100, BV:2000.000, B:'0.008', S:'0.009', SV:6186.400, O:0.009, H:0.009, L:0.009, V:0.900, SC:'5', PV:0.008, P:12.500, BL:'100', P_:'X', V_:''}, {ID:1, N:'3Cnergy', SIP:''.1, NC:'502', R:''.1, I:''.1, M:'t', LT:0, C:0, VL:0.000, BV:31.000, B:'0.021', S:'0.032', SV:22.000, O:0, H:0, L:0, V:0.000, SC:'2', PV:0.021, P:0, BL:'100'.1, P_:'X'.1, V_:''}.1, {ID:2, N:'3Cnergy W200528', SIP:''.2, NC:'1E0W', R:''.2, I:''.2, M:'t'.1, LT:0.1, C:0.1, VL:0.000.1, BV:0, B:'', S:'0.004', SV:50.000, O:0.1, H:0.1, L:0.1, V:0.000.1, SC:'5'.1, PV:0.002, P:0.1, BL:'100'.2, P_:'X'.2, V_:''}.2, {ID:3, N:'800 Super', SIP:''.3, NC:'5TG', R:''.3, I:''.3, M:'t'.2, LT:1.100, C:0.000, VL:35.200, BV:8.100, B:'1.100', S:'1.110', SV:8.700, O:1.110, H:1.110, L:1.100, V:38902.000, SC:'A', PV:1.100, P:0.000, BL:'100'.3, P_:'X'.3, V_:''}.3, {ID:4, N:'8Telecom^', SIP:''.4, NC:'AZG', ...]
```

As you can see, it is not a correct Pandas dataframe and I just can't do anything to read the data inside.
Please advice

Comment: By entering `'http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData?qryId=RAll'` I can confirm that is not a json.

Comment: Indeed, json keys must be enclosed in quotes without any `&&` concatenation. Check with or reach out to API vendor.

Comment: @AntonvBR, any idea how to convert it to json? it has `{}&& {identifier:'ID', label:'As at 08-03-2018 5:06 PM',items:` extra I reckon

Comment: @lotteryman The problem is that the keys are not enclosed with quotes `"`. Looks more like a javascript object. I tried to make a quick google but couldn't find an answer.